# Installing LocalDB on Windows 7

Tags: sql-server, windows-7, installation, localdb

I have windows 7, and I am trying to download SQL Server LocalDB 2014 on it,
but I am receiving the following error.

[image]

I am using an administrator account
the more confusing that I accessed the local Services of the my computer and this service "SQL Server VSS Writer" is already work, it is status is "Started"

what can I do?

Comment: did you look at the sql server installation logs, or event viewer for additional information?

Comment: where can i find this file (installation logs)? @Greg